# How to prevent the TinyMCE (JCE) plugin from cleaning up my code?

Tags: joomla, tinymce, joomla-article, joomla-content-editor

I am using JCE, and I've set everything about code cleanup (in configuration) to OFF. The editor is fixing it anyway. Here's an example:

```
<span class="inset-right">
    <h3>TOC</h3>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#wstep">Wstęp</a></li>
        <li><a href="#jak_zaczac">Jak zacząć?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#spis_metod">Spis metod</a></li>
    </ol>
</span>
```

Will get changed to:

```
<h3>TOC</h3>
<ol>
    <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
</ol>
```

I know it is inappropriate to put `<h3>` and `<ol>` inside of a `<span>` tag, but I do not have a choice here. I just want to turn off all of the code fixing and cleanup.

Comment: [joomla.se] Stack Exchange was not around back when this question was asked, but all Joomla questions are now welcome to be posted there to gain the attention of volunteers with a more intimate understanding of the CMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is invalid. Change span to div and all should be fine....

```
<div class="inset-right">
    <h3>TOC</h3>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#wstep">Wstęp</a></li>
        <li><a href="#jak_zaczac">Jak zacząć?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#spis_metod">Spis metod</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Then it should work...

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2608692 has more information about modifying JCE for your code.

Answer (score 1):

If disabling cleanup using `cleanup: false,` does not help you may define to put H3 and OL list into SPAN as valid.
You may use the following settings depending on your version of tinymce:

- [valid_children](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3avalid_children)
- [extended_valid_elements](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3aextended_valid_elements)

Comment: `cleanup: false` doesn't work. Adding valid elements isn't the solution either, because I gave just one example and there are plenty more. I just want to delete/modify the cleaning up function (if that is possible).

Comment: keep inmaind that even if you are able to disable the cleanup functionality the browser will try to correct semantically incorrrect code (not closed tags aso.)